# Can't click 2nd button in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have 2 sign in buttons with the following code.

```
<div class="text-center mb-3">    <button type="submit" class="btn pink btn-round">Sign in</button>    </div>
```

I used the following code but can't click the second button.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign in')][2]")).click();
```

Comment: What is an error you are getting,

Comment: No such element exception. if i placed index 1, it shows 2 matches. i am testing on php site is that wont be a problem right? where as the page is this http://pellisambandalu.com/signin

Answer (score 0):

Try a different xpath.
This worked for me:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://pellisambandalu.com/signin")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='user_signin_form']/div/div[1]/div[4]/button")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

First Debug it, So you will be getting know whether its working or not,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='text-center mb-3']//button[contains(text(),'Sign in')]")).click();
```